# Sitemaps Broken in Sitemap Index

Tags: magento2, sitemaps, google, multi-language

We are trying to create individual sitemap indexes for our multilingual website.
This is the appropriate solution for handling multilingual websites, but there is another issue we're facing. When we created this:

```
Filename   => sitemap-en.xml
Path       => /media/sitemap/
Store View => English
```

The sitemap index generated is correct but the sitemaps within are changing URL to example.com/en/media/sitemap/sitemap-en-1-1.xml which is a 404 and it doesn't exit.
[image]

**Note that if we remove the /en/ subdirectory the sitemap opens correctly.** How to solve this? What are we missing here?